# RecyclerView LinearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset dose not work

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to scroll the `RecyclerView` to a position, and I use `LinearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset()` to scroll, but it does not work. Could any one help me?

My code:

init the `RecyclerView`:

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

and in the `Button` `onClick`, I do this to scroll the `View`:

```
((LinearLayoutManager)mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, offset);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position)` where position is your current position + offset.