# Android scroll to position in Recylerview not working

Tags: android-recyclerview

I want to scroll the RecyclerView to a position, and I use `LinearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset()` to scroll.

But it does not work. Could any one help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView LinearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset dose not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265476/recyclerview-linearlayoutmanager-scrolltopositionwithoffset-dose-not-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RecyclerView rv = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
rv.setLayoutLayoutManager(layoutManager);
layoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

Scrolling RecyclerView to certain item position can be achieved with LayoutManager which is used with that particular RecyclerView. Plz refer to above piece of code

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a lot of items in your list, you can use `LinearSmoothScroller`

```
val smoothScroller = object : LinearSmoothScroller(activity) {
            override fun getVerticalSnapPreference(): Int {
                return SNAP_TO_START
            }
        }
```

and then when you want to scroll:

```
     smoothScroller.targetPosition = position // position on which item you want to scroll recycler view
     binding.cardsRecycler.layoutManager?.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller)
```